# why the pig getOutputLocations() has wrong results

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I run pig script through java program,and i want get the results about the output locations.So i use the method getOutputLocations() of PigStats.The code like this:

```
            File f1 = new File("myscript.pig");
            f1.deleteOnExit();

            FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(f1);
            fw1.append("A = LOAD 'pig_test/pig_test.txt' USING PigStorage(':');B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 as id;"
                    + "store A into 'pig_test/out005';dump B;store B into 'pig_test/out006';");
            fw1.close();

            String[] args1 = { "-x", "mapreduce",  "myscript.pig" };
            PigStats stats = PigRunner.run(args1, null);

            List<String> listPath = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> listName = new ArrayList<String>();

            listPath = stats.getOutputLocations();
            listName = stats.getOutputNames();
            int i = stats.getNumberJobs();
            System.out.println(i);
            for (String st:listPath) {
                System.out.println(st);
            }
            for (String st:listName) {
                System.out.println(st);
            }
```

As we can see ,in the code ,there are two store,and three jobs:two store and one dump.but the results show in the console was:

```
1
hdfs://192.168.70.181:9000/user/bigdatagfts/pig_test/out006
out006
```

so ,why ?Is there any wrong code i write or anywhere else.Thank you!

Comment: shouldnt the myscript.pig be preceeding a -f argument? Looks like it s a mandatory arg - http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pig/pig/0.9.0/org/apache/pig/Main.java#145

Comment: Thank you,I have try add a -f argument before myscript.pig ,but it has the same result. It looks like doesn't work.

Comment: A is the same as your input. Not sure if PigRunner is optimizing that away into a simple copy and skipping it from the query planner. Can you try the same code with a different pig steps?

Comment: I have try modify the pigscript and the txt file,And change the $0 to $1 ,but it doesn't work.@rahulbmv